# Django- Incorporate django-sites with multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-sites, white-labelling

I am trying to build a white labled product and I am thinking to use django-sites module. I have multiple models of a particular site.
I have found an example like add foreign key of a Site model to a single model. but adding foreign key of Site model to each and every model in every api call, I don't think is a best practice.

Is there any other way to define once and it will add automatically Site id like we use abstract classes for created_at and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it to API calls, you can get the current site from the request (it uses caching as well), and you can create all your models from an abstract model:

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
```

to get a site from the request:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    # Will return a Site instance or RequestSite
    ...
```

Or:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def my_view(request):
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current(request)
    # Don't configure settings.SITE_ID
    ...
```

You can find more examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: Yes, I can get site id from request but How do I identify which model's object is for which site.

Comment: Create an abstract model class with foreign key to site

Comment: and how to add value to these site foreign key automatically like created at and modified at.

Comment: In the view when you create? You need a request for it.